# Not able to parse logs having spaces between key value pair in json

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I have a log containing json object. The log gets parsed if json object has no spaces. If it has spaces between key value pair, it is not getting parsed.

Configuration file used

```
input {
syslog {
port => 3011
}
}

filter {
grok {
match => { "message" =>
[
"%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp4} %{DATA:time_ms}|%{DATA:field1}|%{DATA:field2}|99|%{DATA:field3}|%{DATA:field4}|%{DATA:field5}|%{DATA:field6}|%{DATA:field7}|%{DATA:field8}|%{DATA:field9}|%{DATA:field10}|%{DATA:field11}|%{DATA:field12}|%{GREEDYDATA:field13}"
]
}
}
date {
match => ["timestamp4", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss"]
}
if [field13] {
mutate {
add_field => {"log_type" => "my-logs"}
}
}
}

output {
if [log_type] == "my-logs" {
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["ES_HOST:9200"]
index => "my-logs-000001"
}
}
}
```

Logs getting parsed:

echo "Mar 21 13:27:11 11:11.366293|dataadwhw1|ebsmp4713user5_@maiator|99|4064|22|SUCCESS|data|19|UA101|10.1.1.70|https|data.com|{"wrg_id":"200000337"}|200" | nc localhost 3011
echo "Mar 21 13:27:11 11:11.366293|dataadwhw1|ebsmp4713user5_@maiator|99|4064|22|SUCCESS|data|19|UA101|10.1.1.70|https|data.com|{"wrg_id" :"200000337"}|200" | nc localhost 3011

Log not getting parsed:
echo "Mar 21 13:27:11 11:11.366293|dataadwhw1|ebsmp4713user5_@maiator|99|4064|22|SUCCESS|data|19|UA101|10.1.1.70|https|data.com|{"wrg_id": "200000337"}|200" | nc localhost 3011

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is in CSV format delimited with `|`. So I recommend you to use [logstash csv parser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html).

```
filter {
  csv {
    separator => "|"
    columns => ["syslog_timestamp", "hostname", "username", "integer1", "integer2", "integer3", "result", "category", "integer4", "code", "ip", "protocol", "scheme", "url_host", "json_data", "http_status"]
  }
}
```

> Note: column names generated randomly. Please write the the field name that you want to see.

After that If you want to remove the whitespaces you can use [mutate =>  strip](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-strip).

> Strip whitespace from field. NOTE: this only works on **leading** and
> **trailing** whitespace.

```
filter {
  mutate {
     strip => ["field1", "field2"]
  }
}
```